# Confgure IntelliJ to use the same Java formatter as Spotless

Tags: java, intellij-idea, spotless

I use the [Spotless Gradle plugin](https://github.com/diffplug/spotless/tree/master/plugin-gradle) to ensure consistent formatting of the Java code in my app. The relevant entries in `build.gradle` are

```
plugins {
  id "com.diffplug.gradle.spotless" version "3.27.0"
}

spotless {
  java {
    // The available versions of the Eclipse JDT formatter are defined here
    // https://github.com/diffplug/spotless/tree/master/lib-extra/src/main/resources/com/diffplug/spotless/extra/eclipse_jdt_formatter
    eclipse('4.13.0')
    indentWithSpaces()
    removeUnusedImports()
  }
}
```

Is there some way I can configure IntelliJ to use the same formatting settings?

Comment: I'd ask that on the IntelliJ forum, as the developers who know it the best stalk those forums regularly.

Answer (score 10):

Although Tob's approach works, I use a bit different way of configuring it.

#### 1. Create an external tool in the Preferences

[image]

#### 2. Assign a shortcut for the created external tool

I prefer using `⌘` + `⌥` + `;`, because it's easy to remember (IDEA uses `⌘` + `⌥` + `L` by default).
[image]

#### 3. Use it

Press `⌘` + `⌥` + `;` and wait until all the files are processed and the IDE reloaded changed files. Usually, it takes 2-5 seconds.

Warning: spotless may crash (usually it happens because of mistakes in your code, so be sure your code is compilable):
[image]

Answer (score 8):

A not 100% satisfying but working approach:

**1. Configure the Spotless tasks**

```
spotless {
    format 'misc', {
        target '*.properties','*.gradle', '*.md', '.gitignore' // etc.
        // code style rules
    }
    java {
        // code style rules
    }
}
```

**2. Add task activation to `*Apply` tasks**

[image]

**3. Assign convenient keystroke to `Build Project`**

Do this under `Settings > Keymap`.

*Keep in mind that `Build Project` is using IntelliJ's internal builder. It's incremental (performant), but in case of custom/third-party gradle tasks, the build result might deviate from the `$ gradle build` result.*

In case of a Spring application utilizing DevTools, the build will lead to the changes/updates being served automatically.

---

With the IDE Hook it should be rather trivial to implement a dedicated Spotless formatter plugin for IntelliJ:
https://github.com/diffplug/spotless/blob/master/plugin-gradle/IDE_HOOK.md

So far I wasn't able to find one though.

Comment: It's been a year and amazingly still no plugin for spotless in IDEA, amazing because it seems like it shouldn't be so hard to implement. Running the Gradle task doesn't sound like a bad idea anyway though, and you can hook other cleanup tasks in that way. One improvement could be to use the `idea-ext` plugin to set up the hook without having to use the UI.

Comment: @Hakanai, does the [following](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/18321-spotless-gradle) plugin fit your description?

Comment: @DmitriiBadretdinov maybe. Would have to play with it a bit. I'd prefer it to replace the existing reformat action rather than being a new action, but it looks like it would at least do something.

Answer (score 5):

You can install this plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/22455-spotless-applier.

It allows running the spotless Gradle and Maven tasks from within the IDE, either on the current file selected in the editor or for the whole project.

Comment: I cannot actually find this plugin via settings->plugins->marketplace in my intellij community edition. Im using IDEA 2023.3